# Is there a difference in performance between these two uses of sprintf?

Tags: c, performance, printf

I'm trying to print different days of the week depending on the value of a variable. Each day is mapped by a specific number.

I want something convert number to `Monday`, `Tuesday`, etc. For instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a=1;
    char buf[16];
    sprintf(buf,"%s",a==1?"Monday":a==2?"Tuesday":a==3?"Wednesday":a==4?"Thursday":a==5?"Friday":a==6?"Saturday":a==7?"Sunday":"Unknown day");
    printf("%s",buf);
    return 0;
}
```

I wonder if it's more efficient (performance-wise) to use the following way since all the strings end in the same suffix ("day"):

```
sprintf(buf,"%sday",a==1?"Mon":a==2?"Tues":a==3?"Wednes":a==4?"Thurs":a==5?"Fri":a==6?"Satur":a==7?"Sun":"Unknown ");
```

So, is there a difference in memory usage or performance between these two?

Comment: The performance difference, if any, is likely to be negligible. Especially compared to the awkwardness of reading that code.

Comment: An array lookup will beat both versions. The array lookup will also be much easier to translate into other languages.

Comment: Code using the construct that most clearly express intent. Optimize only when and where needed, and do so with a profiler.

Comment: Both forms are maintenance headaches waiting to happen, and the second form is worse in that respect.  A lookup table will be just as fast and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

The performance difference is certainly negligible. Under the hood, we're considering just a couple more dereferences.

All the strings in your example will be stored in read-only memory (where string literals go) and very likely in contiguous memory locations (right next to each other). Since this is the case, it's also very likely that all the characters making up those strings will be stored in a CPU cache by the machine, reducing the access time down to undetectable.

What is really murdering your efficiency is the nested ternary operators. This generates a lot more assembly than needed.

A better way to do what you want to do is by having an array of the values at the particular indices that map to them. For example:

```
char * days[] = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", ...};

sprintf(buf, "%s", days[a - 1]);
```

Note: `a - 1` since it appears that `a` starts at 1 in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Best to not get fancy at all.

```
/* Returns name of given day of the week,
 * where Monday is day 1, and Sunday is day 7.
 */
const char *dayofweek(int day)
{
    switch (day) {
        case 1:  return "Monday";
        case 2:  return "Tuesday";
        case 3:  return "Wednesday";
        case 4:  return "Thursday";
        case 5:  return "Friday";
        case 6:  return "Saturday";
        case 7:  return "Sunday";
        default: return NULL;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        const char *day = dayofweek(i);
        printf("Day %d of the week is %s\n", i, day ? day : "[invalid]");
    }
    return 0;
}
```